# post array data into codgenitier controller using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have try by other stackover flow tutorial but still problem here simple code
lan_lat is array and store value ex(24.5656,47.67676) I want to pass into 
php controller file pls also refer code in controller to access value form array

This is my view ajax file

```
$(document).on('click','.magic_delete',function(){
    $.ajax({
        // alert(lat_lng.length);
        type: "POST",
        url:'<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/welcome/PasssJavasciptData',
       data: lat_lng
       //dataType: "json"
    }).done(function($msg) {
        alert($msg);
        //jQuery("div#result_table").html($strTable);
    });
}
```

This is my view file

```
public  Function PasssJavasciptData()
{
    $arr = $this->input->post('data');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.Send data in object format `data: {lat_lng:lat_lng}` from ajax to controller then get the value using `$this->input->post('lat_lng');`.

**AJAX:**

```
  $.ajax({

       // alert(lat_lng.length);

              type: "POST",
              url:"<?php echo base_url('index.php/welcome/PasssJavasciptData');?>",

              data: {lat_lng:lat_lng}
              //dataType: "json"
     }).done(function(data) {

                  // alert(success);
                     //jQuery("div#result_table").html($strTable);
      });
```

**Controller:**

```
public Function PasssJavasciptData() {

      $arr = $this->input->post('lat_lng');//array of values
      print_r($arr);//prints array

 }
```

Comment: There is no error I want to return my lat_lng data into .done(function)

Comment: .done(function($msg) {
                
                       alert($msg);
                         //jQuery("div#result_table").html($strTable);
          });

Comment: In done function alert message it not represent  my lat_lng array data (24.5656,47.67676)

Comment: In controller any loop required to collect data  from array and represent into echo?

Comment: actually my target is assign lan lat to controller .in controller i will fetch address of lan lat value then those address return to view file in done() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','.magic_delete',function(){
 $.ajax({
    // alert(lat_lng.length);
    type: "POST",
    url:'<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/welcome/PasssJavasciptData',
    data: lat_lng
    dataType: "json"
 }).done(function($msg) {
    alert($msg);
    //jQuery("div#result_table").html($strTable);
 });
}
```

In this ajax call welcome is controller and PasssJavasciptData is method. So if you want to send data to this controller method. You can retrieve it like this

```
class Welcome() {

   public function PasssJavasciptData() {
      $data = $this->input->post();
      print_r($data);
   }
}
```

Comment: There is no error but I want to return my lat_lng data into .done(function)

Comment: In done function alert message it not represent my lat_lng array data (24.5656,47.67676)

Comment: actually my target is assign lan lat to controller .in controller i will fetch address of form lan lat value then those address return to view file in done() function

Comment: instead of `done`  use `success` then check what you have returned. also remember one thing when you `print` or `echo` it should be **json encoded**.